# Practical data for HP Labs Memristor

Tags: memristor

Has there been any practical experiments conducted with HP Labs fabricated TiO2 memristor? How would I know?

Comment: <sarcasm> It's been 10 years since HP told us all how the memristor was a monumental, fundamental, game-changing discovery/invention that would completely revolutionize the entire electronics industry. I can't believe that a wealth of such data is not available from a plethora of sources. <\sarcasm>

Comment: a 2014 review: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e172/7a86be474ceab3dba4f7060a002f36b0c390.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This isn't HP, but it is titanium. The repeatability on these things doesn't look like the simulated ideal figure 8 graphs.

[image]

Source: https://www.nature.com/articles/srep04522

Comment: Thank you. Although its not exactly what I wanted but its the closest I got.